# Android ListView addHeaderView not working with a simple View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I'm inflating a `View` and adding it to a `ListView` for using it as a padding for the top element within the `ListView`. The problem is that the view doesn't render in the `ListView` unless I change `View` to for example `TextView`, cannot I use a simple `View` here? why?

This is the code for adding the pad:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
view top_pad = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_pad, null);
list.addHeaderView(top_pad);
```

The pad XML file **layout.search_pad**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<View 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="#333" />
```

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I've just edited the question.

Comment: Do you call list.setAdapter before or after list.addHeaderView ?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add an Item of type View to your header, the problem is that if there is nothing telling the view how tall is should be at a minimum, and the view contains no children the ListView will shrink its header to a 0 height.

So to fix my implementation i added in XML a

```
android:minHeight="@dimen/minHeader"
```

where minHeader is

```
<dimen name="minHeader">5dp</dimen>
```

Again a callout here for addHeaderView(View v):

> Note: When first introduced, this method could only be called before setting the adapter with setAdapter(ListAdapter). Starting with KITKAT, this method may be called at any time. If the ListView's adapter does not extend HeaderViewListAdapter, it will be wrapped with a supporting instance of WrapperListAdapter.

Sorry this is late, Happy Coding.